# Protobuf in MinGW64 shell has trouble with absolute path

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw-w64, protoc

MinGW protoc is having trouble with a network share as an absolute path in a MinGW-w64 shell.

```
cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\PROJECT\build\common && protoc --cpp_out="C:/PROJECT/build/common/proto" --proto_path="//VBOXSVR/PROJECT/common/proto" //VBOXSVR/PROJECT/common
/proto/PROJECT.proto && protoc --cpp_out="C:/PROJECT/build/common/proto" --proto_path="//VBOXSVR/PROJECT/common/proto" //VBOXSVR/PROJECT/common/proto/entity.proto &
& protoc --cpp_out="C:/PROJECT/build/common/proto" --proto_path="//VBOXSVR/PROJECT/common/proto" //VBOXSVR/PROJECT/common/proto/player.proto && protoc --cpp_out="C:/
PROJECT/build/common/proto" --proto_path="//VBOXSVR/PROJECT/common/proto" //VBOXSVR/PROJECT/common/proto/sector.proto"
//VBOXSVR/PROJECT/common/proto: warning: directory does not exist.
Could not make proto path relative: //VBOXSVR/PROJECT/common/proto/PROJECT.proto: No such file or directory
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The file exists:

```
$ file //VBOXSVR/PROJECT/common/proto/PROJECT.proto
//VBOXSVR/PROJECT/common/proto/PROJECT.proto: Perl5 module source, ASCII text
```

The CMake foo is straight-forward:

```
set(PROTO_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/proto)
set(PROTO_OUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/proto)
set(PROTO_NETWORK_FILE ${PROTO_PATH}/PROJECT.proto)
set(PROTO_ENTITY_FILE ${PROTO_PATH}/entity.proto)
set(PROTO_PLAYER_FILE ${PROTO_PATH}/player.proto)
set(PROTO_SECTOR_FILE ${PROTO_PATH}/sector.proto)
set(PROTO_SOURCES
    ${PROTO_OUT_PATH}/PROJECT.pb.cc
    ${PROTO_OUT_PATH}/PROJECT.pb.h
    ${PROTO_OUT_PATH}/entity.pb.cc
    ${PROTO_OUT_PATH}/entity.pb.h
    ${PROTO_OUT_PATH}/player.pb.cc
    ${PROTO_OUT_PATH}/player.pb.h
    ${PROTO_OUT_PATH}/sector.pb.cc
    ${PROTO_OUT_PATH}/sector.pb.h
)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${PROTO_SOURCES}
    COMMAND protoc --cpp_out="${PROTO_OUT_PATH}" --proto_path="${PROTO_PATH}" ${PROTO_NETWORK_FILE}
    COMMAND protoc --cpp_out="${PROTO_OUT_PATH}" --proto_path="${PROTO_PATH}" ${PROTO_ENTITY_FILE}
    COMMAND protoc --cpp_out="${PROTO_OUT_PATH}" --proto_path="${PROTO_PATH}" ${PROTO_PLAYER_FILE}
    COMMAND protoc --cpp_out="${PROTO_OUT_PATH}" --proto_path="${PROTO_PATH}" ${PROTO_SECTOR_FILE}
    DEPENDS ${PROTO_NETWORK_FILE} ${PROTO_PLAYER_FILE} ${PROTO_SECTOR_FILE} ${PROTO_ENTITY_FILE}
)
set_source_files_properties(${PROTO_SOURCES} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
```

The error seems to be stemming from protocs inability to handle the weird looking network share path.

What I'm looking for is any ideas on how to work around this problem. I am looking to *keep using my network share*. So, any solution must be a work-around that keeps the network share.
This is a project that is built on both a Linux machine and on Windows from the same build system. It's also fairly big and copying into the machine is not possible right now.

Maybe it's possible to use CMake to copy these files into the build directory and invoke protoc from there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using configure_file to copy the .proto file into the build folder, which is not on a network share.

```
function (process_proto_file FILE)
    set(PROTO_FILE "${PROTO_OUT_PATH}/${FILE}.proto")
    configure_file(${PROTO_PATH}/${FILE}.proto ${PROTO_FILE} COPYONLY)

    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${PROTO_OUT_PATH}/${FILE}.pb.cc ${PROTO_OUT_PATH}/${FILE}.pb.h
        DEPENDS ${PROTO_FILE}
        COMMAND protoc --cpp_out="${PROTO_OUT_PATH}" --proto_path="${PROTO_OUT_PATH}" ${PROTO_FILE}
    )
    set(PROTO_SOURCES ${PROTO_SOURCES}
        ${PROTO_OUT_PATH}/${FILE}.pb.cc
        ${PROTO_OUT_PATH}/${FILE}.pb.h
        PARENT_SCOPE
    )
endfunction()

foreach(FILE ${PROTO_FILES})
    process_proto_file("${FILE}")
endforeach()

set_source_files_properties(${PROTO_SOURCES} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
```

This works fine and solves my problem. configure_file has the bonus feature of adding a dependency towards the real file, which makes changes to the source .proto files cause rebuilds.